# Change the src of an image with an Href

Tags: javascript, jquery

i would like to change the src of an  tag with an "href" from a link tag every 5sec.

This is the code :

```
<div id="bgStretch"><img id="bgStretchimg" src="images/picture1.jpg" alt=""></div> <!--   here is the image src i want to change-->

<nav class="bgNav">
 <ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="images/picture1.jpg"></a></li>
  <li><a href="images/picture2.jpg"></a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
<!--these are the links so i hope you guys to gimme a solution in javascript-->
```

this is the jquery i tried:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var items = $("nav.bgNav ul li");
    var index = -1;

    function next() {
        // if not the very first iteration, 
        // remove the active class from prev item
        if (index !== -1) {
            var urlI=$(this).("a").attr(href);
            items.eq(index).removeClass("active");
        }
        // go to next item
        ++index;
        // if past end, wrap to beginning
        if (index >= items.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        // add active class to next item
        items.eq(index).addClass("active");
    $('#bgStretchimg').attr('src', urlI);
        // schedule next iteration
        setTimeout(next, 1000);
    }

    next();
});

</script>
```

it's not working with me, so i asked you guys and thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? We can help you fix existing code but I will not provide a complete solution...

Comment: I'll check it later, when I got 2 sec, I removed my downvote and upvoted since you edited! Remember to always provide code when asking questions like that so people can help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if it took long!

Here's a [working JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dozoisch/J7VTg/)!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     var items = $("nav.bgNav ul");
     var img = $("#bgStretchimg");

     next();

     function next() {

         var urlI = items.children('.active').children("a").attr('href');

         var nextI = items.children('li.active').removeClass("active").next();
         if (nextI.length == 0) {
             nextI = items.children().eq(0);
         }

         nextI.addClass('active');
         img.attr('src', urlI);

         // schedule next iteration
         setTimeout(function () {
             next();
         }, 2000);
     }
 });
```

If you want a delay before the first call you might want to put it in a setTimeout the same way it is in the function, so it waits before the first change.

```
// in document ready directly
setTimeout(function () {
    next();
}, 2000);
```

---

Might also want to look for a plugin that is already built-up like this one : [jQuery Cycle](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)

Comment: great brother great :)

Comment: @JefferyKilluminati I hope it helps! You were close. The main problem was the first selector `$(this)`

Comment: ahh yeah i was worried bout it, but thank you so much